# Why are karbanos brought on Shabbos?

Tags: shabbat, korban

Rashi to the beginning of Vayakhel points out that despite its importance, the *mishkan* can not be built on Shabbos. However, we find that most karbanos *can* be brought on Shabbos, even though this violates a few *melachos*. What's the difference? (I'm looking for a more hashkafah-oriented answer.)